# Backup Windows Server 2016 (Hyper-V host) )to Azure Recovery Service

Tags: backup, hyper-v, azure, windows-server-2016

In my lab environment I have a Windows Server 2016 acting as Hyper-V host. I would like to back up Hyper-V guests using Azure Backup Server.

I have followed the guide here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup
In step 3.5 I select to backup Hyper-V Guests.

The server where Azure Backup Server are installed needs to be joined to a domain. My Hyper-V Server host isn't joined to a domain. I have no DC (but I can set up a new guest to act as DC and let the Backup Server be joined).

Will it be possible to backup the Hyper-V host outside the domain (it shall not be joined to the domain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it be possible to backup the Hyper-V host outside the domain?

For now, Microsoft Azure Backup Server(MABS) does **not** support backup on-prem Hyper-v vms without domain joined.

In Azure documentation, this [official article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup#1-choose-an-installation-platform) say, the MABS must be domain joined.

> Always join Azure Backup Server to a domain. If you plan to move the
>   server to a different domain, it is recommended that you join the
>   server to the new domain before installing Azure Backup Server. Moving
>   an existing Azure Backup Server machine to a new domain after
>   deployment is not supported.

Comment: Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Ok, so I understand (in a on-prem environment):
MABS must be joined to a domain. And to backup a Host (VM/Physical), it must also be joined to the same domain. That make it hard to backup a i.e. Webserver on DMZ, or another workload that must not be a part of the domain for security reasons.

Comment: @Sam You are right, about six months ago, MABS can backup hyper-v Host without join domain. maybe join domain will find other Hyper-V hosts, but for now, we can't jump this settings:(

Comment: @Sam You could give your feedback to this link, all of the feedback you share in this link will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback  I agree with you, without join domain is good for someone without domain server.

Comment: @Sam Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance. If it helpful, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for pointing in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommended that you join the server to the domain before installing Azure Backup Server.

As it needed the functions of the Active Directory Domain Controller to view the listed domain joined computers and to have domain administrator rights to deploy the Azure backup agent.